# Toilet laws for Transgender people in Japan

Tags: legal, japan, toilets, lgbt

I'm a trans woman heading to Japan on holidays soon.

Are there any particular laws surrounding the toilets in Japan for transgender people? I will be presenting female - but I will be visibly transgender sadly.

I don't really feel comfortable heading into the male bathroom - but I'd also not like to go to jail instead, or face a fine.

I tried googling it, but all I come across are news articles about some high court ruling. I'd like to know what the law actually says (if anything).

Answer (score 64):

Many public toilets in Japan will have, beside the regular gendered male and female toilets, an accessible toilet which is intended for people with disabilities, people with a stoma, people who want to change nappies, people who are with young children, elderly or pregnant people, or anybody else for whom the use of the regular toilets might cause difficulty for any reason.  They are called [多目的トイレ "tamokuteki toire, “multipurpose toilet](https://www.accessible-japan.com/accessible-toilets-in-japan/)” and sometimes "daredemo toire" "anybody toilet".

Here is a sign for such a toilet. They would normally be located beside or between the gendered toilets, where you would find a "disabled toilet" in the UK. However, unlike disabled toilets in the UK, they are designated for use by "anybody". This is the norm for public toilets in department stores, train stations, even on the bullet train and in larger restaurants.

[image]

The text reads "Multipurpose toilet (Some people need multipurpose toilets)"

Comment: +1, but unlike disabled parking spots, disabled toilets are also open to anybody.

Comment: Also, in some restaurants or cafes with just two or three rooms, you often find one is female, one male/female, and if present, the third single sex - they are marked with the usual , , and  icons.

Comment: It's amazing a country can offer a toilet for public use without requiring users to explain themselves. Well done, Japan!

Comment: purely fwiw I don't think i've seen one on a bullet train??  on the shinkansen I've seen, the corridor has (A) simply "a toilet" behind a door, with absolutely no labelling, and (B) there's an open-air (or sort of half-shieled) urinal for men.  i've never seen a male / female / daredemo trio on a train.

Comment: I suppose to be persnickety this has nothing to do with the actual question .. what are the laws.

Comment: @fattie,  I would tend to agree with you, so upvoted the other answer, but there's no accounting for folk, and I think this answer is a useful secondary answer.  I suppose you could say that it is unquestionably legal for a person of any cis/trans status to use the daredemo toire in Japan, though I don't attempt to give specific legal advice.

Comment: @lambshaanxy *disabled toilets are also open to anybody* ... kinda. Using a disabled toilet blocks it for disabled people who may need it. And they may need it NOW. I would tend to level them free and wait for my turn.

Comment: @lambshaanxy no they're not. It's not legally enforced, and in many cases unenforceable (as not all disabilities are visible and you cannot typically be required to divulge medical information justifying your use of a disabled toilet), but disabled toilets are emphatically _not_ for anybody

Comment: You say "many" public places have them, but this is true of the US too. However, usually both male and female bathrooms just have a dedicated stall for people with disabilities and, nowadays, both have changing stations if it's a place that anticipates families. A separate third alternative to the male and female restrooms is too far from universal enough to rely on it. Would it be unusual for a business or public space not have a dedicated disabled restroom or is this pretty much the standard in Japan?

Comment: I don't know about the USA, my experience is only in the UK. Disabled toilets are designated for people with disabilities, and are not for anybody.

Comment: @JamesK There are no legal restrictions on who can use any public toilet in the UK. Period. Whether able people *should* use them is a separate ethical question, but the OP in particular would have an entirely sensible reason to.

Comment: Are you aware of the RADAR key ?

Comment: For context, I come from Australia - this is very common here too. I was just wondering if it was also possible to use the female bathrooms if there was a long line for the disabled toilets, or it wasn't available.

Answer (score 42):

From a legal point of view, **the situation is muddy at best**.  Japan does [recognize transgender people](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBT_rights_in_Japan) and it's possible to legally change your gender, but the bar to doing so is quite high and merely being female presenting is not enough.  There is also [recent court precedent](https://time.com/6293956/japan-supreme-court-transgender-restroom/) (July 2023) that transgender women can use women's bathrooms at work.

In practice, though, Japan is very much a "mind your own business" society where people avoid getting involved in the affairs of strangers, so **it's exceedingly unlikely** that anybody would call the cops on you for merely using a female bathroom.

Comment: Go in, don't look at people, do your stuff, come out. If you don't bother others, then you give them no reason to bother you.

Comment: You also very occasionally see older women popping into the male toilets when there is too long a queue in the ladies. Also, note unlike in the USA, toilet doors are gap-free, so no-one's going to accidentally catch a glance at what you're up to.

Comment: But if somebody did call the cops, they have a 99% conviction rate, yes?

Comment: @user253751 For cases the police choose to prosecute, which they only do if they have an ironclad case.

Comment: @lambshaanxy If they _think_ they have an ironclad case. Which is a huge issue in its own right, because it literally hurts a prosecutor's career to lose a case, and this, along with keeping up the image of a 99% conviction rate, puts pressure on the courts to convict even if there are cracks in the case.

Comment: @Arthur No, the pressure works in the other direction, they will not prosecute if they have any doubts. I've personally experienced Japanese police straight up refusing to register a wallet as pickpocketed, insisting it was "lost" instead.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any particular laws surrounding the toilets in Japan for
> transgender people?

I'll be first to answer the actual bathroom law question. Firstly, there is no bathroom law in particular, but it falls under the jurisdiction of trespassing law ([住居侵入等](https://keiji-soudan.jp/crime/jukyoshinnyu/),
article 130).

Here's what it states:

> Article 130 of the Criminal Code.
> A person who, without justifiable cause, enters a person's residence or a residence, building or ship guarded by a person, or fails to leave these places despite being requested to do so, shall be punished with imprisonment for a term not exceeding three years or with a fine not exceeding 100,000 yen.

Thus if you were to obtain permission from the owner of the building where the toilet resides in, you will be able to use whichever toilet regardless of your presentation.

However, [another law](https://www.keishicho.metro.tokyo.lg.jp/about_mpd/keiyaku_horei_kohyo/horei_jorei/meiwaku_jorei_kaisei.html) comes into play if a third party sees you and reports you to the police, which falls under "Violation of the Anti-Nuisance Ordinance (迷惑防止条例違反), and states:

> Nuisance prevention ordinances are ordinances set by each prefecture
> and other local authorities prohibiting nuisance behaviour towards the
> public.

In many municipalities, the official name is 'Ordinance on the Prevention of Violent Delinquent Acts, etc. that Cause Extreme Disturbance to the Public' (e.g. Tokyo Metropolitan Government and Osaka Prefectural Government).

Basically, a nuisance act committed in a public place or in a public vehicle is a violation of the nuisance prevention ordinance.

...and transgender individuals have been arrested for it in the past.

Thus, the only **legal recommendation** is to use the gender neutral toilet (多目的トイレ）.

Short list of transgender individuals who have been arrested for toilet use in the past 2 years (by request):

- [Jan 6 2022: Osaka Prefectural Police announced on the 6th that he entered the women's restroom of a commercial facility in Osaka City](https://www.asahi.com/sp/articles/ASQ166FXRQ16PTIL006.html)
- [3 cases mentioned here (2022/1, 2021/9, 2021/5) main takeaway is 'pre-op individuals cannot be recognized as transgender', so it actually uses the term crossdressing, but if you read the context they fit the transgender definition.](https://times.abema.tv/articles/-/10011263?page=1)
- [2023 Nov 13: Transgender woman arrested for entering women's bath](https://news.yahoo.co.jp/articles/b4d438b197eafc71754b45475f315c93553e10fc)
- [2023 Sep 1: "I thought people recognized me as a woman" - man arrested for entering women's toilet](https://www.chiba-tv.com/plus/detail/20230984262)

There are a **ton** more articles, but as explained, they are rarely ever tagged 'transgender' due to public and lawful perception.

Bonus: ["Gender neutral toilet removed as it breeds crime"](https://news.yahoo.co.jp/articles/2371e99b2f9acd950c3096396986b9f90d3e11cb)

Comment: Would you have a cite for transgender people being arrested for merely using a toilet?

Comment: @lambshaanxy I added 6 incidents from 4 sources, hope that's enough. At least one person gets arrested on a monthly basis since the early 2000s.

Comment: Also, Japanese news articles get deleted anytime between 1 week and a few years, which makes it pretty impossible to find online sources after a while unless you remember the title.

Comment: Thanks!  Although as I suspected many of these cases aren't that clear cut, the 2nd and 4th are for entering a women's bath (not toilet) and the 5th says "女子トイレに侵入し盗撮しようとした" (entered the toilet to commit voyeurism).

Comment: Yeah it's hard to be clear cut as it becomes a he-says she-says kind of case. しようとした is used when there is alleged intention to, but no clear evidence.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend researching the areas you'll be visiting to see if there are any establishments with gender-neutral restrooms because it really depends on the establishment, but most places in Japan has a gender-neutral restroom.

Comment: That does not seem to add much to the two existing detailed answers. Can you edit to give more details?

Comment: Seems like a good answer to me.

Comment: "most places in Japan" [citation needed] Having lived in Japan well over a year, I can safely say that outside of very small businesses with a single toilet for all customers, I have never encountered the concept of "gender-neutral restroom". Even public toilets in parks, etc. are usually gendered. Edit: There are often restrooms for handicapped people, which are not gender-specific, but I wouldn't go as far as to call that a gender-neutral restroom.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your personal experience. It is valuable to learn about different perspectives and experiences. Yes, there are gender-neutral restrooms in some places in Japan, especially in urban areas like Tokyo. Except for restaurants and entertainment facilities, have restrooms without gender designation. These restrooms are located in public buildings such as government buildings, libraries, and parks in Tokyo. Gender-neutral restrooms in Japan are not yet universal, and there still may be many businesses and public places in the country that do not offer such facilities.

Comment: I live in a city of ~800,000 and the only "Gender-neutral" toilets I've seen are in convenience stores. Everywhere else has male and female toilets, and sometimes a special toilet for disabled people, usually just a special stall, and that's it. I think you're overstating how many places have gender-neutral toilets by a very wide margin. @natiiix After 8+ years living here, this answer really surprises me.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Sorry, my statement about the prevalence of gender-neutral toilets may have been overstated, and availability varies by location. However, the push for inclusive restrooms is gaining momentum, and the goal is to create welcoming spaces for people of all gender identities.

Answer (score -3):

The laws surrounding the toilets in Japan for transgender people are not very clear or consistent. There is no national law that explicitly protects the rights of transgender people to use the bathroom that matches their gender identity, but there are also no laws that explicitly prohibit it. The legal situation depends largely on the local authorities and the individual establishments.